# In SQL how do I increment id like this: client1, client2, client3

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'd like to hear some advice on designing the tables in this database...

Let's say I have 3 tables: Shirts, Pants and Shoes

They all have the same fields: Name, Description, Manufacture, Material and ID
I can't simply put the IDs as 1, 2, 3, 4 for each of them so I've decided to a notation: shirt001, shirt002, pants001, pants002, pants003 and so forth. I know this isn't the correct way to design it so should I just combine it into one big table and have the fields as Name, Description, Manufacture, Material, ID with an extra 'Type' field?

Comment: Why can't you put the IDs as 1,2,3,4,... Your data is in different tables so you are not going to have any collisions. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: When I do a text search, (Select Name, Description, Manufacture, Material, ID from Shirts, Pants, Shoes) it returns: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous. I'm testing this on WAMP.

Comment: See my answer below, having an ID that is used for multiple types is bad design, and could lead you into problems.

Comment: I added the SQL version to my answer.

Comment: The structure with three different tables is fine. You just need to change your text search SQL to distinguish which table is which.

Comment: ANd don;t name id fields ID, tablenameid is much clearer. Also , you should NEVER use implicit join syntax. Very poor techinique that leads to bad bugs. for instance  "Select Name, Description, Manufacture, Material, ID from Shirts, Pants, Shoes" is a cross join which wil return more records than you want. Very poor query design even with the bad database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should make one database table that defines all of the different products:

```
Table:   Product 
Columns: ID (pk, identity),
         ProductTypeID (fk to ProductType table),
         Name,
         Description, 
         Manufacture,
         Material

Table:   ProductType
Columns: ID (pk, identity),
         Name,
         Description
```

Comment: Thanks Yaakov, do you know if MySQL's MyISAM can have foreign keys and such?

Comment: Looks like as of MySql 5.0, MyISAM doesn't support foreign key constraints - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html. Currently only InnoDB supports it, though it is "planned" for MyISAM in a later version.

Comment: Thanks. Uhh this is bad... going to have to switch my whole DB to InnoDB.

Comment: If you have a specific reason to use MyISAM, then you don't necessarily have to switch. You would just not be able to rely on the DB to enforce the FK constraint, and you would have to be extra careful about doing this in code. (But if there is no good reason to stick, then better to do it now and get it over with - FK constraints are a good thing).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: MySQL added to bottom of answer**

The database design you are quoting doesn't adhere to first normal form (1NF).

It'd be more beneficial to you if you split your database into multiple tables, with a Type table. This would produce a relational database that doesn't have duplication, and the IDs wouldn't clash if there was a user error.

```
Table: Item
       Id          (int, auto-increment) [PrimaryKey]
       FkTypeId    (int) [ForeignKey]
       Name        (string)
       Description (string)
       Material    (string)
       Manufacture (string)

Table: Type
       Id          (int, auto-incrememnt) [PrimaryKey]
       Name        (string)
```

You can now insert your types into the Type table (Shirt, Pants, Shoe, etc) and associate each item with their relavent Type.

Here is a wikipedia page on first normal form, something you should try to adhere to in any database design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

**Here is MySQL version of my suggestion:**

**NOTE THIS WORKS IN MyISAM**

```
CREATE TABLE ProductType (
  Id INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name VARCHAR  NOT NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(Id));


CREATE TABLE Product (
  Id INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ProductType_Id INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL  ,
  FkTypeId INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL  ,
  Name VARCHAR  NOT NULL  ,
  Description VARCHAR  NOT NULL  ,
  Material VARCHAR  NULL  ,
  Manufacturer VARCHAR  NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(Id, ProductType_Id)  ,
INDEX Product_FKIndex1(ProductType_Id),
  FOREIGN KEY(ProductType_Id)
    REFERENCES ProductType(Id)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Quick question if you dont mind: What is the SQL that is equivalent to FROM [no table]?

Comment: @stockoverflow added the MySQL version

Comment: while the statement will work on MyISAM the foreign key constraints will **not** be enforced!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, put it into a single table, with a foreignkey `TypeID` that links to a table `ItemTypes`.

Comment: Wasn't me (haven't registered), maybe it was too short?

Comment: I think it opretty much covered the original question? Dont you think?